# Можно ли использовать libcrypto в программах с закрытым кодом?

Tags: opensource, gnu

libcrypto - библиотека, написанная под GNU GPL 2.0. Существуют ли исключения, позволяющие использовать libcrypto, не открывая исходный код моей программы и не обязывающие использовать GNU GPL в моей программе?

Comment: Откуда инфа? Как я понял, libcrypto — часть OpenSSL, у которого и близко никакого GPL нету

Comment: @andreymal, действительно. Нет там никакого GPL... Я уш перепугался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Надо тщательнее проверять инфу. По запросу "libcrypto license" первой же ссылкой гугл выдает GitHub юзера, у которого есть проект, лицензированный под GPL, со схожим названием. Библиотека libcrypto лицензирована OpenSSL License, которая не подразумевает открытие исходного кода.

Прошу прощения, мой косяк :)